# How to update field with the same code

Tags: mysql

I want to Update the field UPDATPARAM when PARAM has word apple, update only the first row  where clause = CODE

```
ID CODE PARAM UPDATPARAM
1  L12  MANGO  
2  L12  APPLE
3  L12  ORANGE
4  L13  APPLE  
5  L13  MANGO
6  L14  ORANGE
7  L14  MANGO
8  L14  Apple
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
ID CODE PARAM UPDATPARAM
1  L12  MANGO    APPLE
2  L12  APPLE
3  L12  ORANGE  
4  L13  Apple   Apple 
5  L13  Orange
6  L14  ORANGE Apple
7  L14  MANGO
8  L14  Apple
```

Comment: what does it mean? Do you want to update the first row if there the param is 'apple' at least once? What if the param value is apple in more than one row?

Comment: This question needs clarifying and a bit more thought put into it.

Comment: my sample query UPDATE Table AS t
  JOIN 
    (SELECT CODE
      FROM Table  where PARAM='APPLE 
     
    ) AS m 
    ON t.CODE= m.CODE
SET t.UPDATPARAM= 'APPLE'  But the output is                                    ID CODE PARAM UPDATPARAM
1  L12  MANGO    APPLE
2  L12  APPLE       APPLE
3  L12  ORANGE    APPLE My desired output should only update the first row based on where clause CODE.

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy UP

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE your_table_name_here
SET UPDATPARAM = 'APPPLE'
WHERE PARAM LIKE 'APPLE';
```

May be this could help you

Comment: This doesn't match desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You might want this

```
drop table if exists t;

create table t(ID int, CODE varchar(3), PARAM varchar(20), UPDATPARAM varchar(20));
insert into t(id,code,param) values
(1 , 'L12' , 'MANGO' ), 
(2 , 'L12' , 'APPLE'),
(3 , 'L12' , 'ORANGE');

update t as t1 join t t2 on t2.id = t1.id + 1
set t1.updatparam = t2.param
where t2.param = 'apple' and t1.id = 1;

select * from t;

+------+------+--------+------------+
| ID   | CODE | PARAM  | UPDATPARAM |
+------+------+--------+------------+
|    1 | L12  | MANGO  | APPLE      |
|    2 | L12  | APPLE  | NULL       |
|    3 | L12  | ORANGE | NULL       |
+------+------+--------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```